# What is my problem filling forms with LWP and HTTP::Request::Form?

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I'm new to Perl, currently writing a Perl script to automatically fill web forms and submit them using LWP. The website URL is `***/something.cgi` and in that document there is a form I need to fill, then hit submit. That takes me to another page which has another form to fill, but the website's URL remains the same.

I managed to fill the first form and submit it using:

```
$res = $ua->request($f->press("submit"));
```

where

```
my $f = HTTP::Request::Form->new($forms[0], $url);
```

Viewing `$res->as_string` shows the next page source, but tried to get the new forms in order to fill it, but it gave me the same form I already have. How can I get next page in order to fill its forms and proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you look at [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#SYNOPSIS) and its [form methods](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#FORM_METHODS) which is a subclass of [LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent).

**EDIT**

Adding an example closely based on the example from my first link:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( 'http://google.com' );
sleep 1; ## be nice

$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 0,
    fields      => {
        q       => 'mungo',
    }
);

print $mech->content;
```

Comment: thanks, wondered if you can provide more specific example, im new to perl and web programming, and can't manage to understand since no examples are found in the LINK you provided. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The form you are trying to script must be using some paramter or cookie to determine which page of the multi-page form to process.  Look at the cookies returned in

```
print $res->header();
```

to see if there are cookies being set for a session-ID or other parameter that you need to pass back in.

Also, look at the source of the first form page vs the second, see if there are hidden input types that indicate that the second submission is for the second form page. Or, look at the value of the submit button tag, maybe that is different on the second page.